# How to group rspec descriptions in the html output result

Tags: ruby, rspec, watir-webdriver

I have a number of rspec specifications in different files. But they all are close related so I decided to describe them all likewise. The problem is that the output html is grouping the scenaries by file and not by the description. Something like that:

Rspec file 1:

```
describe "Module 1" do

    it "should do something " do
    ...
end
```

file 2:

```
describe "Module 1" do

    it "should do another thing " do
    ...
end
```

The html result is like this:

```
Module 1 ---------
    should do something
Module 1 ---------
    should do another thing
```

The result ideally should be that way:

```
Module 1---------
    should do something
    should do another thing
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Why don't you group specs(`it 'should' do` blocks) for the same controller/model/whatever under the same file?

Comment: Cause they will get very large...

Comment: I had a similar issue when using Cucumber. I think you will need to create a custom formatter.

Comment: Had you solved your problem?

Comment: Yes, a custom formatter did solve my problem. Basically I took the HTML formatter and made changes where required. Though if I were to do it again, I would output the results into xml and then translate the xml to html report. I think it would give better control over the report rather than hacking various methods. You should be able to do similar in Rspec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay! The custom formatter did the trick. Thanks to all help!